# Iterate over array/list inside a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use this linq query to check if certain object's netIds are null, blank, or otherwise empty.

```
var badData = FileSignatures.Drive.Public.Where(
    e => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(
        e.NetworkBlock?.Select(n => n.netId)) &&
         String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(
             e.WiFiBlock?.netId) &&
             String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(
                 e.BluetoothBlock?.netId))
    .ToList();
```

WiFiBlock and BluetoothBlock are both just single objects so the above should work.

However, NetworkBlock is an array of objects so I need to figure out how to iterate through each object in NetworkBlock and check it's netId.

Is it possible to do something like that inside a linq query?

Thanks!

Comment: `e.NetworkBlock?.Any(n => String.IsNullOrWhitespace(n.Id))` or something of that nature. It's an enumeration; you can do anything with it in that lambda that you could anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing!

change this:

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(
        e.NetworkBlock?.Select(n => n.netId))
```

to this:

```
e.NetworkBlock?.Any(n => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n.netId)) ?? false // or true depending on criteria
```

or using `All` depending on your criteria.

full code:

```
var badData = FileSignatures.Drive.Public.Where(
    e => (e.NetworkBlock?.Any(n => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n.netId)) ?? false) &&
         String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(
             e.WiFiBlock?.netId) &&
             String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(
                 e.BluetoothBlock?.netId))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks like it should work but I am getting "cannot convert from bool to string".

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell that shouldn't be with the code I've introduced. look carefully elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Oh ok, I know that 'false' is a boolean, so I thought it might have been trying to convert that to a string.  It was because I forgot an open parentheses!